# A line in JS function disappears a button

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm trying to make a button that opens a prepopulated sms with content from form fields. Once I add the row that should open the sms, the button disappears.

```js
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
btn.innerHTML = "Send";
btn.onclick = function() {
  var firstname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  var lastname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
  window.open(`sms://12345678/?body=${encodeURIComponent(firstname + lastname)}`, '_blank');
};
document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="Examplename" <br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Examplename">
</form>
```

Comment: Please fix the errors in your javascript code.

Comment: Try this window.open('sms://12345678/?body='+encodeURIComponent(firstname "+" lastname),'
      _blank ');

Comment: `window.open(\`sms://12345678/?body=${encodeURIComponent(firstname + lastname)}\`, '_blank');`

Answer (score 0):

I believe all you have to do is fix the various JavaScript errors in your code. Considering the following version:

```js
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
btn.innerHTML = "Send";
btn.onclick = function() {
  var firstname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  var lastname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
  window.open(`sms://12345678/?body=${encodeURIComponent(firstname + lastname)}`, '_blank');
};
document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="Examplename" <br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Examplename">
</form>
```

Note that pop-ups aren't allowed in the StackOverflow snippet sandbox.